# Modular equivalence in Agrawal's conjecture

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

In Agrawal's conjecture:

> If $r$ is a prime number that does not divide $n$ and if $(X-1)^n ≡ X^n-1 \pmod{X^r-1, n}$, then either $n$ is prime or $n^2 ≡ 1\pmod r$.

How to understand $\pmod{X^r-1, n}$?

I searched for "modular equivalence" but did not find an answer for this notation (with comma in parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply remainder left after dividing $X^{r}-1$ by $n$.

Comment: I doubt that. In another paper it is written as $(X-1)^n ≡ X^n-1 \pmod{n, X^r-1}$.

Comment: See this : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45855/what-is-the-current-status-of-agrawals-conjecture. if you can get some hint here.